# Как сделать кнопку с обрезаными углами html/css

Tags: html, css, button

Мне надо получить такие кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос: как мне их сделать через `css`.

спасибо на ответы.

Comment: зацените https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/

Comment: не очень подходит - https://codepen.io/imergames/pen/bGpGGyx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131937/css-button-with-two-cut-off-corners

Comment: Я думал над `псевдо.элм` но проблема в том что на сайте кнопки в разных блоков и будет выходить так - https://codepen.io/imergames/pen/bGpGGyx, так что надо будет постояно менять цвет `псевдо.элм`, и я подумал пожет есть более удобный способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
:root {
  --size-skew: 1rem;
}

.btns {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #C1E532;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #272727;
  color: #fff;
  clip-path: polygon(var(--size-skew) 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--size-skew)), calc(100% - var(--size-skew)) 100%, 0 100%, 0 var(--size-skew));
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: #272727;
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--size-skew), var(--size-skew) 0, 100% 0, 100% calc(100% - var(--size-skew)), calc(100% - var(--size-skew)) 100%, 0 100%, 0 var(--size-skew), 2px calc(var(--size-skew) + 0.83px), 2px calc(100% - 2px), calc(100% - var(--size-skew) - 0.83px) calc(100% - 2px), calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - var(--size-skew) - 0.83px), calc(100% - 2px) 2px, calc(var(--size-skew) + 0.83px) 2px, 2px calc(var(--size-skew) + 0.83px));
  pointer-events: none;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  background-color: #000;
}

.btn-outline {
  color: #272727;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:focus,
.btn-outline:active {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
  <button class="btn">En</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline">Personal account</button>
</div>

<div class="btns red">
  <button class="btn">En</button>
  <button class="btn btn-outline">Personal account</button>
</div>
```